# creating TimeSeries object of fastdtw library

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use [fastdtw library](https://github.com/davidmoten/fastdtw).

The readme file explains how to create TimeSeries object:

```
TimeSeries ts1 = TimeSeriesBase.builder()
    .add(0, 123.4)
    .add(1, 125)
    .add(2, 126.3)
    .build();
```

Frankly, I've got more than 3 items to input. So I'd like to use iterations using an array of values.

This code just adds one value to the last position of iterator:

```
TimeSeries ts = null;    
for (int i = 0; i < audioBuffer.length; i++)
{
    ts = TimeSeriesBase.builder().add(i,audioBuffer[i]).build();
}
```

How can I create a `TimeSeries` object of much bigger size?

Thanks for any help.